# iPhone MKMapView: Detecting Nearest Locations in Array from Current Location

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mkmapview

I have an Array with approximately 1,000 Objects, each of which has a precise coordinate value.  What I would like to do is take a Search button that I have and, when pressed, detect the current location and calculate 10 nearest Objects to this location.  Any advice for the best way to go about this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That formula only works for flat surfaces where the grids in each direction are the same. This is true at a small scale at the equator, but the further away from the equator you get the closer the lines of longitude get to each other, whilst the latitude lines are still the same distance apart.

For example from Auckland one degree of latitude is ~111.2Km and one of longitude is ~88.8Km. So the grid is not square. Effectively meaning that from (0,0) it is further to (0,1) than (1,0).

The proper solution is to use Apple's CLLocation and its getDistanceFrom: (or distanceFromLocation: ) which calculates true distances based on the surface of a sphere (using WGS84 projection I think).

Answer (score 1):

Mark,

Yes, this is quite easy.  All you have to do is loop through the array and calculate the distance between each one and your present location.  Then, you can keep the ten records with the lowest distance.

The distance formula is just:

```
( (x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2 ) ^ (1/2)
```

So I'd have an `NSMutableArray` as I looped, and then do a push-pop type algorithm to return the lowest 10.

If you need help with the coordinate code, let me know.

Comment: keep in mind that if you are only interested in comparing distances (not the actual distance values), you don't need to do the square root, just compare the distSquared value

Comment: tato, good shout, didn't occur to me - I was too busy regurgitating high school math :)

Comment: Though this answer is marked as accepted, it is not correct because the world is not flat and lat/long is not a square grid. Scroll down for an answer that uses Apple's API to get the correct distance between points.

Comment: Craig, you're absolutely correct.  I should have indicated that this formula is approximate and skews towards the ends of the earth.  I didn't realized when I posted.  I've upvoted your answer and I hope the OP switches it.